# Model performance with multiply imputed data

Tags: roc, multiple-imputation, calibration

I would like to know how to do calibration plot with Hosmer-lemeshow test and AUC for ROC curve after multiple imputation in R. I build one prediction model and tried to do model performance but noticed that it is not simple.

I also tried pool_performance function in psfmi package, but showed the following error.

```r
Error in cut.default(pred, quantile(pred, c(seq(0, 1, 1/groups_cal)))) : 
  'breaks' are not unique
```

Could you tell me if this function is ok to use for model performance with multiply imputed data set, otherwise the better R code and example?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a smaller number of groups using the groups_cal option in the function, e.g. try 8 or 6, because the spread of predicted probabilities of your model seems too small for 10 groups.